# String contains specification for nested properties

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to implement a contains specification for nested properties. I am currently working off a contains specification below that only supports a simple property.

For an object structure like below and applying the specification to the Manager Entity.

```
public class Manager
{
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public Department Department { get; set; }
   public IList<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
}

public class Department
{
   public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Employee
{
   public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

It is able to support a filter like below.

```
[
    {
        "Name",
        "John"
    }
]
```

The problem comes when I need to support a more complicated query like below.

```
[
    {
        "Employees.Name",
        "Jake"
    }
]
```

I think the specification will also have to behave different for a filter like this because it is not looking into a collection and just a single object.

```
[
    {
        "Department.Name",
        "Accounting",
    }
]
```

The contains specification that I currently have now

```
private static Expression<Func<T, bool>> CreateExpression(IDictionary<string, string> filter)
{
    var type = typeof(T);
    var parameterExpression = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));

    var aggregatedExpression = filter.Aggregate((Expression)null, (agg, pair) =>
    {
        var propertyInfo = type
            .GetProperties()
            .FirstOrDefault(t => t.Name.Equals(pair.Key, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
        if (propertyInfo == null)
        {
            throw new Exception("PropertyInfo was not found.");
        }

        // Call to string on value if property is of the listed property types
        var propertyExpression = (Expression)Expression.Property(parameterExpression, propertyInfo);
        if (propertyInfo.PropertyType == typeof(long) ||
            propertyInfo.PropertyType == typeof(long?) ||
            propertyInfo.PropertyType == typeof(int) ||
            propertyInfo.PropertyType == typeof(int?) ||
            propertyInfo.PropertyType == typeof(DateTime) ||
            propertyInfo.PropertyType == typeof(DateTime?) ||
            propertyInfo.PropertyType == typeof(Guid) ||
            propertyInfo.PropertyType == typeof(Guid?))
        {
            var toStringMethod = propertyExpression.Type.GetMethod(nameof(ToString), new Type[] { });

            if (toStringMethod != null)
            {
                propertyExpression = Expression.Call(propertyExpression, toStringMethod);
            }
        }

        var containsMethod = propertyExpression.Type.GetMethod(nameof(Queryable.Contains), new[] { propertyExpression.Type });
        if (containsMethod == null)
        {
            throw new Exception("Contains method is not found.");
        }

        // Call contains on the property (i.e. Name.Contains("John")
        var expression = Expression.Call(propertyExpression, containsMethod, Expression.Constant(pair.Value));

        // Multiple Contains to be aggregated into OrElse
        agg = agg == null ? expression : (Expression)Expression.OrElse(agg, expression);

        return agg;
    });

    return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(aggregatedExpression, parameterExpression);
}
```

Comment: Why specification works with property names? How you define specification, by code or it is deserialized from some string?

Comment: We find the PropertyInfo by iterating through the list of properties. We then create an expression with that property. We define the specification through a FilterDto a dictionary of PropertyName and Value.